# Python function to select all municipalities

Tags: python, pandas

So I want to import some data from the Dutch databank CBS. I need to select all the municipalities. They all have a code that starts with GM and then 4 numbers.

Do I have to type them all in? Or is there a quicker way to get them all in in one time.

```
# Downloaden van selectie van data
data = pd.DataFrame(
      cbsodata.get_data('70072ned', 
                          filters="RegioS eq 'GM0003', 'GM0004', 'GM0005'",
                          select=['RegioS', 'Vrouwen_3', 'Mannen_2']))
print(data.head())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how `cbsodata.get_data` works but it seems to me that you could generate `filters`.

```py
filters = "RegioS eq " + ", ".join(["'GM" + str(i).zfill(4) + "'" for i in range(3, 8)])
```

This will give you:

```
"RegioS eq 'GM0003', 'GM0004', 'GM0005', 'GM0006', 'GM0007'"
```

Which you can use as `filter` variable.

---

Example:

```py
filters = "RegioS eq " + ", ".join(["'GM" + str(i).zfill(4) + "'" for i in range(3, 8)])

data = pd.DataFrame(
    cbsodata.get_data(
        "70072ned",
        filters=filters,
        select=["RegioS", "Vrouwen_3", "Mannen_2"],
    )
)
print(data.head())
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like you can use ODATA querying. If you try the following you'll the idea how to modify the GM019 to just GM and it'll return what you need.

```
pd.DataFrame(
     cbsodata.get_data('70072ned',
     filters="startswith(RegioS, 'GM019')"))
```

You'll get anything starting with GM019

Same data, filtered for columns

```
pd.DataFrame(
     cbsodata.get_data('70072ned', 
     filters="startswith(RegioS, 'GM019')",
     select=['RegioS', 'Vrouwen_3', 'Mannen_2']))
```

Side note: while returning everything (no filters or select), the dataset wasn't large, but it did take a while (couple minutes) to get the data.